# Keeping updated my data at Firebasefirestore is causing duplicating my data in Android Studio Reycyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I created a recyclerview that retrieves items from firebasefirestore when I delete a data from firebasefirestore recyclerview refresh itself normally but when I add an item to firebasefirestore it is refreshed but dublicates the datas and so many items appears in the recyclerview but it shouldnt, and when I enter other activity then exit to this activity a few times my recyclerview backs to normal.This is my method to fill the recyclerview:

```
private void fillArray() {
    NoteArray = new ArrayList<>();

    //SnapshotListener read and write data in real time 
    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if(error !=null){
                Toast.makeText(recyclerview_notes.this,"Error "+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if (value!=null && !value.isEmpty()){
               
                  for(QueryDocumentSnapshot docs:value) {
                      Note note = docs.toObject(Note.class);
                              NoteArray.add(note);
                            
                }
                recyclerViewAdapter = new NotesRecyclerViewAdapter(NoteArray,recyclerViewInterface);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          
            }

        }
    });
```

1.[first I have 2 items in recyclerview:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KyP8.jpg)

2.[then I added third item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOL1g.jpg)

3.[it saves item but dublicates all items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORM6T.jpg)

4.[when I enter other activity and exit a few times it is fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVfwe.jpg)

I  want that when I add a data to firebase , my recyclerview updates normally.

Comment: The data is duplicated because you're notifying the entire adapter and not only a position that has changed. Since you're still using a RecyclerView, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, then I also think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help because it explains how to add/remove elements from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it shows the same data so many times but stored properly on database. Then just clear your list before adding data to the list. Like this `NoteArray.clear();`

See the updated code below

```
private void fillArray() {
    NoteArray = new ArrayList<>();

    //SnapshotListener read and write data in real time 
    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if(error !=null){
                Toast.makeText(recyclerview_notes.this,"Error "+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if (value!=null && !value.isEmpty()){
                  NoteArray.clear(); // adding list clear function. If data is fetched successfully then the list gets cleared old data and fills new data.
                  for(QueryDocumentSnapshot docs:value) {
                      Note note = docs.toObject(Note.class);
                              NoteArray.add(note);
                            
                }
                recyclerViewAdapter = new NotesRecyclerViewAdapter(NoteArray,recyclerViewInterface);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          
            }

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @mehmetaliduran It's my pleasure